# Node.js v10.6.0 App cannot connect to MongoDB 2.4 in Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: web-server, node.js, compatibility, mongodb

If I want to start my node.js (v10.6.0) app on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ (OS Raspbian Stretch) via

```
npm run start:prod
```

and my MongoDB (v2.4) was started before via

```
sudo mongod
```

I receive this error message

```
info: Runnning in production mode (server/dist/index.js)
info: Starting server on port 8000...
info: Connecting to database at mongodb://localhost:27017/mldms...
(node:1826) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
warn: Couldn't connect to a database: MongoError: Server at localhost:27017 reports wire version 0, but this version of Node.js Driver requires at least 2 (MongoDB2.6).
```

I read from another forum you can only download MongoDB version 2.4 for Raspberry Pi. Is there any possibility to fix this problem, so I can connect to my MongoDB? I was also thinking of downgrading node.js.

Comment: Upgrading to a new versions is usually better for security patches, but in this case MongoDB seems a bit of a challenge. https://andyfelong.com/2018/03/mongodb-3-2-64-bit-running-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-caveats/   Downgrading nodejs is also an option if you absolutely need to. I considered MongoDB myself for Rpi3 but just went with a small, simple SQL database such as SQLite3.

Comment: I tried to reinstall node.js and I now have version 8.11. the version of npm is 6.1.0 and of Angular CLI 6.0.8. But I still couldn't connect to my Mongo Database. Are there any bug fixes or something? If not I will try SQLite3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NoSQL databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) such as MongoDB were developed for solving different problems than SQL databases. MongoDB, for example, is a [document-oriented database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database), which might be an unusual application for a Raspberry Pi given its relatively small store (e.g., 16GB SD card).

A more typical Raspberry Pi database application might, for example, involve sensor-based automation. For Raspberry Pi applications that store and analyze regular datastreams (e.g., timestamped temperatures, humidity, etc.), it's enough to use a simple SQL database such as [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html).

Going downrev for compatibility with Nodejs is a tricky proposition. Nodejs regularly incorporates [security updates](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/july-2017-security-releases/) which might not be available in a downrev version. And upgrading MongoDB [can be challenging on Raspberry Pi](https://andyfelong.com/2018/03/mongodb-3-2-64-bit-running-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-caveats/).

For Raspberry Pi databases, choose the simplest SQL or NoSQL database your application requires. The Raspberry Pi has limited resources and over-featured software works against you.